# Really strange problem with SSH disconnecting immediately, lots of investigation done

Tags: debian, ssh, raspberry-pi, sshd

I have 3 raspberry pis with identical SD cards, for some reason one of them suddenly disconnects immediately after SSH authentication.

The problem doesn't occur immediately, reboot will fix it, and then it reoccurs after a short time.

I only see it on 1 of the pis. Issue also occurs SSHing with another valid key from a different computer.

So I see:

```
+----[SHA256]-----+
Last login: Wed Feb 22 12:59:45 2023 from 192.168.7.93
Connection to strawberrypi.lan closed.
```

I know there are tonnes of questions on this topic with answers ranging, I've tried lots of things:

`/etc/passwd/` is good, no `/bin/false`:

```
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
```

Output of `w` on the problematic box shows:

```
 14:24:35 up 15:07,  2 users,  load average: 0.27, 0.19, 0.19
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
pi       tty7     :0               Tue23   15:07m 49.48s  0.16s /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE
pi       tty1     -                Tue23   15:07m  0.12s  0.10s -bash
```

Which seems OK as it's got a GUI running.

I checked the `.bash_rc` `.profile` `.bash_profile` etc, identical across all pis.

I can execute commands with and checked `/var/log/auth.log`

I see only:

```
Feb 22 14:18:24 strawberrypi sshd[5685]: Accepted publickey for pi from 192.168.7.60 port 50331 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:...
Feb 22 14:18:24 strawberrypi sshd[5687]: Received disconnect from 192.168.7.60 port 50331:11: disconnected by user
Feb 22 14:18:24 strawberrypi sshd[5687]: Disconnected from user pi 192.168.7.60 port 50331
```

Also, `/var/log/messages` doesn't seem to help:

```
Feb 22 14:16:21 strawberrypi kernel: [53976.371460] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:34:2c:c4:8a:46:69:08:00 SRC=192.168.7.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=39975 PROTO=2
Feb 22 14:18:26 strawberrypi kernel: [54101.533131] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:34:2c:c4:8a:46:69:08:00 SRC=192.168.7.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=39979 PROTO=2
```

my `ssh -vvvv` shows:

```
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Wed Feb 22 14:17:18 2023 from 192.168.7.60
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 7 efd 8 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 6 efd 8 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/8 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to strawberrypi.lan closed.
Transferred: sent 2696, received 2044 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 69971.5, received 53049.6
debug1: Exit status -1
```

SSH config is identical across working and problematic pis.
Issue reoccurs within an hour or so.

It's kernel version `5.15.52-v7l+` on `Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`

Any ideas?

Output of `sshd debug`:

```
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='10022'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 10022 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 10022.
debug1: Bind to port 10022 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 10022.
```

Comment: Do you have `strace` on the recalcitrant pi?  `strace -f -o /path/to/output/file -p [sshd pid]`.  That should capture the system calls made on the server side, and should provide at least a hint as to what's happening, and it might even reveal the exact cause.

Comment: thanks @AndrewHenle - trace attached, nothing obvious to me...

Comment: @AndrewHenle - there should be nothing sensitive in that trace right? - no key material?

Comment: Can you try `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 10022` and then connect to this debugging instance of ssh on port 10022. Does that give any clues (it's less heavy to read than using strace)

Comment: will do @roaima - thanks for your help, there isn't anything sensitive in the trace output right?

Comment: @Woodstock This is probably the problem:  `5977  --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xa2d83c} ---`.  The `sshd` process forked to handle the connection looks like it crashes.  There might be some sensitive data in there if you're using passwords.  If so, just change the passwords.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - no passwords only public/private keys, I don't think that any keys are exposed, only ephemeral ones.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - do you know what that means?

Comment: @roaima - debug connects, and doesn't disconnect, pasted output above, thank you.

Comment: @Woodstock I'd look at `/proc/PID/maps` of the `sshd` process and see where address `0xa2d83c` happens to be.  And look for core files and see what's in `/var/log/messages`.  If you look at the `strace` output, you'll see *something* got logged.

Comment: Sshd isn't crashing. sshd launches a copy of bash to handle the session, and bash is getting a SIGSEGV while it's setting up the TTY. It's not clear what is causing it. The last file read by bash was "/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color"; maybe it's corrupt?

Comment: @Kenster thanks, it works after reboot though, which seems strange...

Comment: Did you consider the hardware? Swap power supply, wifi card, network cable... (don't know what's used and swappable).

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1770124/432690).